# Where do I find the available icons of react-bulma-components?

Tags: reactjs, bulma

I am learning React using the Bulma framework, I installed react-bulma-components and I want to add some icons. To do so, I imported Icon from "react-bulma-components/lib/components/icon" and then used the component. It works fine, but the Icon component receives an icon property, which is a String of the desired icon and I want to know what the available icons to use are. I found a couple of examples [here](https://couds.github.io/react-bulma-components/?path=/story/icon--default) but I don't know where to find the other available icons. Right now I'm looking for a trash or delete icon.

Answer (score 2):

Import the font awesome in your code and then get the strings related to the icon you wish to use.Here is the link for your reference

https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/trash

```
import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import Icon from 'react-bulma-components/lib/components/icon';
import faUserPlus from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid/faUserPlus';

<Icon>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserPlus} />
</Icon>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Bulma has only this two icons included (`bars` and `angle-down`).
You can check more about it [here](https://github.com/couds/react-bulma-components/issues/36).

The idea is to let the developer choose which icon library he wants to use with bulma. And for it you can use libraries like [Material Design Icons](https://materialdesignicons.com/), [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/), etc...